# How to apply ng-class on button click

Tags: javascript, angularjs

[Plunker.](https://plnkr.co/edit/J2kDize9Bx9hQyatOfMV?p=preview)

TO my textbox I want to apply that `errorhilight` class when the ng-model contains `''` or `undefined`, and when the submit button click only it need's to check.

```
<input type="text" class ="errorhilight" ng-model="name"  ng-class="{'errorhilight': (name == '' || name == 'undefined')}">
```

How can I apply `errorhilight` class on button click.

Comment: Please provide code snippets in your question in the event your plunker is taken down. Might also want to look into https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: @Dom I have edited the question

Comment: https://plnkr.co/edit/YuxJtHvGAamJ5G6D75Qn?p=preview

Comment: @sachilaranawaka good Answer but, is it possible to check the name == '' || name == 'undefined' in html itself

Answer (score 5):

There are many ways you could do it. For example

```
<input type="text" ng-model="name"  ng-class="{errorhilight: highlightErrors && !name}">
<input type="submit" ng-click="validate();">

$scope.validate = function(){
  $scope.highlightErrors = true
}
```

Comment: thanks for quick reply is, it possible to check the `name == '' || name == 'undefined'` in html itself

Comment: Do you mean `{errorhilight: (name == '' || name == undefined)}`?

Comment: yeah I mean the same

Answer (score 0):

```
<input type="text" class ="errorhilight" ng-model="name"  ng-class="{'errorhilight': (name == '' || name == 'undefined')}">
```

Lets look what you are doing wrong . Here you added the class  `class ="errorhilight"` with and without the condition remove that .

2nd part keep a variable for highlights .  Make it true when button is clicked like  @Yury Tarabanko solution . But the best way would be  to use from validators.

```
<form id="testForm" name="testForm"   ng-submit="validate()"  novalidate>

    <input type="text" ng-model="name"  name="name" 
       ng-class="{errorhilight: buttonClicked &&  testForm.name.$invalid}"  required >

     <input type="submit" ng-click="validate();">

</form>
```

and in the controller

```
$scope.buttonClicked = false;
$scope.validate = function(){
  $scope.buttonClicked = true;
}
```

Comment: if you are going to down vote at least leave a comment  to say whats wrong ..

Comment: I need to validate by checking `{'errorhilight': (name == '' || name == 'undefined')}.` in the html itself

Comment: required does that for you .. if the value is not there this will do the both .. why would you want to use   `(name == '' || name == 'undefined')`  when `testForm.name.$invalid` is more cleaner .. using required tag makes it automatically invalid if you dont have any value for the name model